# dockerized postgresql listing no clusters

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, docker

I'm upgrading an existing dockerized postgres:9.6 to 10. There are plenty of good Q/As on DBA and SO that go the path of `pg_upgradecluster`, but it is not working for me.

When I start a vanilla pg:10 instance, whether I mount the old volume or not, `pg_lsclusters` is empty.

```
root@server:# docker run -it -d --name pg10 postgres:10
...
fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
...
2018-07-15 05:11:52.569 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2018-07-15 05:11:52.635 UTC [68] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-07-15 05:11:52 UTC
2018-07-15 05:11:52.651 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Connections work:

```
root@server:# docker exec -it pg10 psql -h localhost -U postgres postgres
psql (10.4 (Debian 10.4-2.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

But clusters are not found:

```
root@server:# docker exec -it pg10 su postgres -c pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory Log file
```

(Nothing given.) If that will work, then I'm intending to mount the old db volume as another cluster (via steps listed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233300/3358272).

I don't understand enough about the db layout to know why the default postgresql image does not produce its default database as a cluster that can be seen with this utility. Help?

**Edit**: the current installation lists them just fine, though it's an instance of `sameersbn/postgresql`, not the pg-central version:

```
root@server:# docker-compose exec postgresql pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.6 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

The [library image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) defaults to creating a new database under `/var/lib/postgresql/data` (no version, no `main`).

Comment: `/var/lib/postgresql/data` looks un-debian

Comment: It's [in the `Dockerfile` as `FROM debian:stretch-slim`](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/eff90effc6b5578be90bef93d96b3fceb1082a7c/10/Dockerfile#L2), and it's the explicit default for `PGDATA` in the [docker hub library readme](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) (scroll down to the *Enrivonment Variables*/`PGDATA` section). How does that even matter, @Jasen?

Comment: version and main come from pg_wrapper, a debian thing to allow multiple instances and versions of postgres to co-exist. I don't know much about docker. debian specific docs in  /usr/share/doc/postgresql-common

Comment: Thanks, that's been helpful to hunt some more down. I think it's because the container [uses `initdb` to create the new database](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/10/docker-entrypoint.sh#L72) vice using `pg_createclusters`. I'm trying to override that, hoping it'll facilitate the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(This is a weak answer, and I'll happily consider other answers if offered.)*

Ultimately, instead of trying to migrate the pg-way, I did it manually with a raw dump of the data, started a new instance, and reloaded/reconfigured from scratch. This involved shifting from the [`sameersbn/postgresql`](https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/postgresql) image (that, as of this writing, has not been updated in over a year) to the canonical [`postgres`](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) image. Since shifting to that image, all upgrades/migrations have gone without issue.

---

**Update**: I've been quite happy with the [`tianon/postgres-update`](https://hub.docker.com/r/tianon/postgres-upgrade) set of docker images for upgrading. It's straight-forward to use; adding to the default run, I add a mount for SSL certs and have been quite happy with:

```bash
# docker-compose stop postgres && echo y | docker-compose rm -v postgres
# docker run --rm \
  -v /my/path/docker/postgres/ssl/:/ssl/ \
  -v /my/path/docker/postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql \
  tianon/postgres-upgrade:13-to-14 --link
# docker-compose up -d postgres
```

(The `/ssl` portion is required based on the configuration in the `/13/` path of files.)